# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths causes SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sigabrt

I've read a lot of posts, but can't find the answer. 
I added in my project MGSwipeTableCell, https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell .

I added .h files:  `#import "MGSwipeTableCell.h"`, and  `"MGSwipeButton.h"`.

Also added:

```
@interface BuyItemListViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, MGSwipeTableCellDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

In storyboard i set MGSwipeTableCell class to my cell. As written in help of this custom control.

So, when i try do delete row with my custom button, a get that deleteRowsAtIndexPaths causes SIGABRT:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    //return self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"itemCell";
    MGSwipeTableCell *cell = [self.itemTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransitionBorder;
    cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransitionBorder;

    cell.leftButtons = [self createLeftButtons:1];
    cell.rightButtons = [self createRightButtons:1];

    cell.delegate = self;

    BuyItemEntity *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self applyCellValues:cell :item];

    return cell;

}
```

*The Error is in this code:*

```
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion
{

    NSLog(@"Delegate: button tapped, %@ position, index %d, from Expansion: %@",
          direction == MGSwipeDirectionLeftToRight ? @"left" : @"right", (int)index, fromExpansion ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft && index == 0) {
        //delete button
        NSIndexPath * path = [_itemTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"indexpath swipe: %i", path.row);

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        BuyItemEntity *itemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
        [context deleteObject:itemToDelete];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if(![context save:&error]){NSLog(@"Eror TableView deleting! %@", error);} //---the object delete correctly

        [_itemTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft]; // here is SIGABRT

        NSLog(@"Delete button pressed");

    }
```

But in Demo application of this class there are no problems,  the code from Demo:

```
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion
{

    NSLog(@"Delegate: button tapped, %@ position, index %d, from Expansion: %@",
          direction == MGSwipeDirectionLeftToRight ? @"left" : @"right", (int)index, fromExpansion ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft && index == 0) {
        //delete button
        NSIndexPath * path = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [tests removeObjectAtIndex:path.row];
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        NSLog(@"Delete button pressed");
    }

    return YES;

}
```

I enabled Zombie Object in debug options for more information.

http://s020.radikal.ru/i700/1410/3d/f63fbedbcff7.png

```
Convenience callback received (right).
2014-10-27 12:11:22.576 NotesApp_1[4885:247508] Delegate: button tapped, right position, index 0, from Expansion: NO
2014-10-27 12:11:22.576 NotesApp_1[4885:247508] indexpath swipe: 2
2014-10-27 12:11:22.580 NotesApp_1[4885:247508] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:1314
2014-10-27 12:11:22.585 NotesApp_1[4885:247508] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 0 which only contains 2 rows before the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0206d946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cf6a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0206d7da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x0196a810 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x007c3f56 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 4313
    5   UIKit                               0x007dc421 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 337
    6   UIKit                               0x007dc49f -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 56
    7   NotesApp_1                          0x000587dd -[BuyItemListViewController swipeTableCell:tappedButtonAtIndex:direction:fromExpansion:] + 749
    8   NotesApp_1                          0x0005f815 -[MGSwipeButtonsView handleClick:fromExpansion:] + 789
    9   NotesApp_1                          0x0005f9bc -[MGSwipeButtonsView buttonClicked:] + 108
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d0c7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    11  UIKit                               0x006cf23d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    12  UIKit                               0x006cf1cf -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    13  UIKit                               0x00802e86 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    14  UIKit                               0x008032a3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    15  UIKit                               0x0080250d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    16  UIKit                               0x0071f60a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    17  UIKit                               0x007200e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    18  UIKit                               0x006e5549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    19  UIKit                               0x006f537e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    20  UIKit                               0x006c9b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01f911df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01f86ced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01f86248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01f85bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x01f859fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x0501424f GSEventRunModal + 192
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x0501408c GSEventRun + 104
    28  UIKit                               0x006cd8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    29  NotesApp_1                          0x0006af2d main + 141
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x02883ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

In that time my old method works correctly, without using custom cell class:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        BuyItemEntity *itemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [context deleteObject:itemToDelete];

        NSError *error = nil;

        if(![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Eror TableView deleting! %@", error);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Read the crash info correctly.
reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 0 which only contains 2 rows before the update'
Means you are deleting an object at index 2 of an array of size 2 (index starts from 0) which is out of size of the array.

Comment: NSIndexPath * path=[_itemTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"number of cliked row: %i \n",path.row);
NSLog(@"number of fetched objects before delete: %i", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count);
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[self managedObjectContext];
BuyItemEntity *itemToDelete=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
[context deleteObject:itemToDelete];
NSError *error = nil;
if(![context save:&error]){NSLog(@"Eror TableView deleting! %@", error);}
NSLog(@"number of fetched objects after delete: %i", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count);

Comment: 2014-10-27 17:55:42.559 NotesApp_1[5678:345693] number of cliked row: 2 
2014-10-27 17:55:42.559 NotesApp_1[5678:345693] number of fetched objects before delete: 3
2014-10-27 17:55:42.567 NotesApp_1[5678:345693] number of fetched objects after delete: 2

Sow, i try do delete row at line number 2, also there are rows at number 1 and 0, And i have 3 objects in my database. Where is mistake, i don’t understand. What code I should modify?

Comment: I've replaced the deleting of row before deleting the object in my database, and get new message: 
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Answer (score 0):

You are out of `bounds`. The first row has index 0, so 2 rows start with index 0 and end with index 1.

Comment: Higher is new log, please help

Comment: Seems you are bit confused about your stored objects and indexes. There is something wrong with your stored data you are trying to remove bcs of inconsistancy.

Comment: Now there is another mistake

Comment: The problem is solved! the method deleteRowsAtIndexPaths isn't needed to use in my case, because program update the table in fetchedResultController. So, only deleting the object in my data is needed. Thanks for your answers.